# Getting html page using get http request and sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, http

Im trying to print the html page https://pastebin.com/raw/7y7MWssc

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

void main(){
    WSADATA WSA;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&WSA) ;

    char  Request[] = "GET /raw/7y7MWssc HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n" ;
    char  Response[2000] ;

    SOCKET  Socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 );
    struct sockaddr_in Server;
    struct hostent *H = gethostbyname("pastebin.com") ;

    Server.sin_addr.s_addr  = *( (int *)H->h_addr);
    Server.sin_family       = AF_INET;
    Server.sin_port         = htons( 80 );

    connect(Socket , (struct sockaddr *)&Server , sizeof(Server)) ;
    send(Socket , Request , strlen(Request) , 0)  ;
    int Rs = recv(Socket , Response , 2000 , 0) ;
    Response[Rs] = 0 ;
    printf("%s\n", Response );

    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

But i keep getting 400 Bad Request as response , but when the request is "GET /raw/7y7MWssc HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: pastebin.com\r\n\r\n" i get 301 Moved Permanently to the Location: https://pastebin.com/raw/7y7MWssc
Thanks for help

Comment: sounds like you know how to fix it then?

Comment: It moved permantly to *https* not *http*, meaning the server doesn't accept regular HTTP anymore but only secure HTTP over TLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a `400 Bad Request` error because you're sending an invalid request. You've declared that you're using `HTTP/1.1`, but an `HTTP/1.1` request must include a `Host:` header.  Compare this:

```
$ telnet pastebin.com 80
Trying 104.23.98.190...
Connected to pastebin.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /raw/7y7MWssc HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: cloudflare
Date: Wed, 14 Apr 2021 17:48:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 155
Connection: close
CF-RAY: -
```

To this:

```
$ telnet pastebin.com 80
Trying 104.23.98.190...
Connected to pastebin.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /raw/7y7MWssc HTTP/1.1
Host: pastebin.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 14 Apr 2021 17:49:32 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Wed, 14 Apr 2021 18:49:32 GMT
Location: https://pastebin.com/raw/7y7MWssc
cf-request-id: 097319bbec00005b119e0df000000001
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 63fec562aa1c5b11-IAD
```

Note how the second request, which includes a `Host:` header, returns the expected response rather than a `400 Bad Request` error.

---

To actually fetch the content from the final location, you'll need to update your code to make `https` requests.

Comment: Any idea how to make the https request ?

Comment: The comments here aren't really an appropriate place for that discussion. I think some brief searches here on SO might result in some relevant sample code.

Comment: Use a HTTP library for that. You will probable encounter encodings and compression that you don't want to deal with (as in: implement yourself).

Comment: @SinusPi HTTPS is just HTTP over an SSL/TLS-encrypted connection. That means you will have to make a new TCP connection to port 443 and negotiate an SSL/TLS handshake before you can then send any HTTP requests over that now-encrypted connection. Use a library to handle that encryption for you, like OpenSSL, etc. Don't try to implement SSL/TLS yourself.